# Calculating angle from latitude and longitude

Tags: r, latitude-longitude, angle

I have a set of latitudes and longitudes , so this is the data for an animal as it moves in time. what i want to do is to calculate turning angle, that is by what angle it turns between every movement. so say i have point 1, point 2 and point 3 with latitude and longitude value corresponding to each point(animal moves from point 1 to point 2 to point 3 and so on) and i want to calculate the angle between these 3 points, point 2 being the middle point. what should i do? my OS is windows and i am using R for analysis.

so here is my sample data:

```
longitude                       latitude
36.89379547                0.290166977
36.89384037                0.290194109
36.88999724                0.286821044
36.88708721                0.288339411
36.88650313                0.29010232
36.88563203                0.289939416
36.88545224                0.290924863
```

they are in decimal degrees

Comment: What have you tried? At least show that you have tried to search for something, and/or show that you understand the math involved.

Comment: i tried to convert the lat and long into x and y coordinates in km, assuming earth is spherical(for simplicity). and then i tried to use the cosine formula to calculate the angles. but i am getting extremely small values for the angles which seem practically highly unlikely. any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Show your code and some sample data, otherwise we can only guess what your problem is. Are you working in degrees or radians?

Comment: i am not able to upload this column wise. so the way it has got uploaded is longitude(e.g.36.89379547) followed by latitude(e.g.0,290166977)

Comment: Is this for some four-legger trotting about in the woods, so that the overall range of lat & lon is small, allowing approximation as flat 2D space, or is this for whales or birds who migrate thousands of miles, requiring 3D geometry?

Comment: Try putting that sample data in the question itself, instead of as a comment

Comment: so this is for a four legger!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using the function `trackAzimuth` in `maptools`:

```
library(maptools)

trackAngle <- function(xy) {
    angles <- abs(c(trackAzimuth(xy), 0) -
                  c(0, rev(trackAzimuth(xy[nrow(xy):1, ]))))
    angles <- ifelse(angles > 180, 360 - angles, angles)
    angles[is.na(angles)] <- 180
    angles[-c(1, length(angles))]
}
```

The `trackAzimuth` function is a simple loop wrapper around `gzAzimuth`. See `?gzAzimuth` for references on calculating directions on the sphere.

Using your data:

```
x <- read.table(text = "longitude                       latitude
36.89379547                0.290166977
36.89384037                0.290194109
36.88999724                0.286821044
36.88708721                0.288339411
36.88650313                0.29010232
36.88563203                0.289939416
36.88545224                0.290924863", header = TRUE)

trackAngle(as.matrix(x))
[1]  10.12946 111.17211 135.88514  97.73801  89.74684
```

EDIT: I had to remove first/last angles from the function, something I was doing after the fact with this function elsewhere. Should be right now. :)

Also, the packages `adehabitatLT` and `argosfilter` contain functions to calculate track directions and angles.

Comment: Should the ifelse statement in trackAngle function be removed? It silently changes angle direction from clockwise to counterclockwise when angles > 180. You can't actually appreciate that azimuth 89.7° and 97.7° are 172° apart, as the second one actually is 262.3°.

Comment: Ah good point, I was just thinking of a measure of acuteness, not direction.

Answer (score 0):

Your data points vary over only a small range.  We can look at one small patch of Earth's surface and pretend it's flat, two dimensional.  You have to figure out the scale of how many km, meters, miles, whatever your favorite unit is, corresponds to one degree of latitude, and for one degree of longitude. The latter depends on latitude - it'll be the same as the scale for latitude when near the equator, but if you are standing within arm's length of the north pole, one step will take you through fifty degrees.  Set up x,y coordinates where x=0 is at longitude 36.88000, and y=0 is latitude 0.29000.

So, now you have a series of (x,y) points.  Take the differences from each point to the next: P2-P1, P3-P2, etc.  These could be called "displacement vectors" but other terms may be used in other fields than where i'm from.  Call them V1, V2, etc.  Use dot products and norms:  dot(V1,V2) = magnitude(V1)*magnitude(V2)*cos(a) where a is the angle by which V2 deviates from the direction of V1.  Repeat for V3 and V2, and so on.

R has all the tools to do this, but I don't know enough syntax of R to give examples.