# Calculate the angles between lat/long coordinates with moving animal

Tags: r, gps, angle

I want to work out what the green and yellow angles are on the diagrams. The red line is the movement of animal 1 with each numbered point representing its location at each time point (rowid in the data). A3 represents the position of animal 3 when animal 1 is at point 2.

To work out the orange angle, I think I need to work out the angle drawn on in black and then do 180° minus the black angle, but i'm not sure how to work out this either.

I want to work this out for each timepoint in the data, a sample of which i've included below. In some cases I don't have the location of animal 3 which is fine and the angle can be NA. I've included 2 diagrams to show the different situations that could occur. The crs= 4326. Any help is much appreciated!

[image]

[image]

```
rowid,id,t_,lon,lat,Animal3.lon,Animal3 .lat
1,Animal 1,01/01/2017 06:19,-9.95545,3.777097,#N/A,#N/A
2,Animal 1,01/01/2017 08:45,-9.93917,3.774998,-9.95192,3.789981
3,Animal 1,01/01/2017 16:34,-9.94561,3.779115,-9.94959,3.783688
4,Animal 1,01/02/2017 08:18,-9.94575,3.784986,-9.94617,3.798219
5,Animal 1,01/02/2017 15:57,-9.94198,3.794307,-9.94861,3.802043
6,Animal 1,01/03/2017 07:24,-9.9353,3.783469,-9.9472,3.795541
7,Animal 1,01/03/2017 17:44,-9.93446,3.775781,-9.93526,3.81313
8,Animal 1,01/03/2017 19:33,-9.94091,3.773766,#N/A,#N/A
9,Animal 1,01/04/2017 06:33,-9.93553,3.775065,-9.93203,3.799718
10,Animal 1,01/04/2017 17:01,-9.93588,3.779135,-9.93348,3.796017
11,Animal 1,01/05/2017 08:43,-9.92929,3.774276,-9.93471,3.794776
12,Animal 1,01/05/2017 16:43,-9.92989,3.778653,-9.93755,3.803964
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution based on a simplified version of the matrix you provided. Credit to @mdsummer's function - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184381/calculating-angle-from-latitude-and-longitude) - which I modified only slightly.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(maptools)
library(sf)

# Function - get angle from set of three points 
trackAngle <- function(xy) {
  
  if(any(is.na(xy))){return(NA)}
  
  angles <- abs(c(trackAzimuth(xy), 0) -
                  c(0, rev(trackAzimuth(xy[nrow(xy):1, ]))))
  angles <- ifelse(angles > 180, 360 - angles, angles)
  angles[is.na(angles)] <- 180
  angles[-c(1, length(angles))]
  
}

# Original Matrix
animal_mat <- t(matrix(c(-9.95545,3.777097,NA, NA,
                         -9.93917,3.774998,-9.95192,3.789981,
                         -9.94561,3.779115,-9.94959,3.783688,
                         -9.94575,3.784986,-9.94617,3.798219,
                         -9.94198,3.794307,-9.94861,3.802043,
                         -9.9353,3.783469,-9.9472,3.795541,
                         -9.93446,3.775781,-9.93526,3.81313,
                         -9.94091,3.773766,NA, NA,
                         -9.93553,3.775065,-9.93203,3.799718,
                         -9.93588,3.779135,-9.93348,3.796017,
                         -9.92929,3.774276,-9.93471,3.794776,
                         -9.92989,3.778653,-9.93755,3.803964), 4, 12))

## Reformat to get lists of points 

# Other animal angles
animal_pts1 <- map(2:nrow(animal_mat), function(idx){
  
  animal_pt <- unname(animal_mat[idx,][c(1,2)])
  other_pt <- unname(animal_mat[idx,][c(3,4)])
  animal_last_pt <- unname(animal_mat[idx-1,][c(1,2)])
  
  animal_pts_mat <- rbind(animal_last_pt, animal_pt, other_pt)
  
  animal_pts_mat
  
})

# Main animal angles
animal_pts2 <- map(2:(nrow(animal_mat)-1), function(idx){
  
  animal_pt <- unname(animal_mat[idx,][c(1,2)])
  animal_last_pt <- unname(animal_mat[idx-1,][c(1,2)])
  animal_next_pt <- unname(animal_mat[idx+1,][c(1,2)])
  
  animal_pts_mat <- rbind(animal_last_pt, animal_pt, animal_next_pt)
  
  animal_pts_mat
  
})


## Angles 

# Other animal angles (11)
other_animal_angles <- 180 - map(animal_pts1, ~trackAngle(.x)) %>% unlist

# Main animal angles (10)
main_animal_angles <- 180 - map(animal_pts2, ~trackAngle(.x)) %>% unlist


## Combining angles info
angles_tbl <- tibble(main = main_animal_angles, other = other_animal_angles[1:10])

## Final dataframe   
angles_tbl %>% mutate(tot = main+other)

# A tibble: 10 x 3
    main   other   tot
   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 155.  138.    292. 
 2  56.0  16.4    72.4
 3  23.3   0.451  23.8
 4 126.   62.5   189. 
 5  25.4 167.    192. 
 6  78.8 175.    254. 
 7 176.   NA      NA  
 8  81.3  68.3   150. 
 9 131.   13.0   144. 
10 134.  141.    275.
```

Note that you get angles greater than 180 with this solution, so something may be wrong here (possible with CRS?). Technically, it is possible to get values greater than 180, although I don't know if it makes sense in practice because I don't have any domain knowledge that would give me a sense of what angles are possible in this setting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I assume this code is to work out the orange angle in the diagram?  If so the first angle could make sense as the diagram is not accurate or to scale, sorry I should have made that clear. Do you know how I could extend this code to also work out the green angle?

Comment: I used this code to calculate the green angle, @bbspring would you mind checking if it is correct? `animal_pts <- map(2:nrow(animal_mat), function(idx){ animal_pt <- unname(animal_mat[idx,][c(3,4)]) other_pt <- unname(animal_mat[idx-2,][c(1,2)]) animal_last_pt <- unname(animal_mat[idx-1,][c(1,2)]) animal_pts_mat <- rbind(animal_last_pt, animal_pt, other_pt) animal_pts_mat }) #same code for track angle   map(animal_pts, ~trackAngle(.x)) %>% unlist`

Comment: You'll want to rewrite that part of the code to collect the animal_next_pt instead of other_pt. To do this, change `unname(animal_mat[idx,][c(3,4)])` to `unname(animal_mat[idx+1,][c(1,2)])`. You'll also want to change the beginning of the function from `2:nrow(animal_mat)` to `2:(nrow(animal_mat)-1)`

Comment: So it is like this? @bbspring (Sorry I just want to double check everything) `animal_pts <- map(2:(nrow(animal_mat)-1), function(idx){
  
  animal_pt <- unname(animal_mat[idx+1,][c(1,2)])
  animal_next_pt<- unname(animal_mat[idx-2,][c(1,2)])
  animal_last_pt <- unname(animal_mat[idx-1,][c(1,2)])
  
  animal_pts_mat <- rbind(animal_last_pt, animal_pt, other_pt)
  
  animal_pts_mat
  
})
`

Comment: Change `rbind(animal_last_pt, animal_pt, other_pt) ` to `rbind(animal_last_pt, animal_pt, animal_next_pt) `

Comment: I've done that now @bbspring but it gives me angles for all data points even when it should be NA, any idea why this is?

Comment: Hmm. The map functions should split the data into lists, which contain 3x2 matrices where each row represents a set of coordinates. You then map over this list entering the elements into the trackAngles function to get an angle for each element. I'll look at this more deeply tonight (woo Friday!) if I have time.

Comment: Any chance you've managed to have a look @bbspring ? No worries if not, I've had a go but can't seem to work it out

Comment: Hey @Bett21, I've added a new answer that includes the animal (last, current, next) point angles, along with a dataframe that has the sum of corresponding angles. Don't know if it makes sense to get angles greater than 180. These angles are only possible if the main animal moves backwards AND the other animal is behind the main animal's current location. So it's technically possible but may not make sense. Could be a crs issue, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hi @bbspring Thank you!! I'll try it with my full dataset to see if the angles make sense. So the other animal angle is the orange angle and the main animal angle is the green one? If this is the case, can I ask why there is `180-map` for both of the angles?

Comment: The other animal angle is (1-2-A3), so (180 - other animal angle) is the orange angle. The main animal angle is (1-2-3), so (180 - main animal angle) is the (green - orange) angle. In the final step, we add these together to get (A3-2-3).

Comment: Thanks again for your help @bbspring , I've tried this with my full data and I think I know the issue that meant a lot of the angles are over 180. In some cases, A3 can be on the otherwise of the red line (I'll add another diagram) and therefore doesn't equal 180 - main animal angle and add orange angle. Do you think it's possible to calculate A3-2-3 using the same method as to get 1-2-A3?